# Comparing lines inside a vector<string>

Tags: c++

How do you read lines from a vector and compare their lengths? I have pushed strings inside a vector and now would like to find the longest line and use that as my output. I have this as my code all the way up to comparing the strings:

```
ifstream code_File ("example.txt");

size_t  find_Stop1, find_Stop2, find_Stop3, find_Start;
string line;
vector<string> code_Assign, code_Stop;


if (code_File.is_open()) {
    while ( getline(code_File,line)) {



        find_Start = line.find("AUG");                        // Finding all posssible start codes
        if (find_Start != string::npos) {
            line = line.substr(find_Start);
            code_Assign.push_back(line);                            //adding line to Code_Assign


            find_Stop2 = line.find("UGA");                              //  Try and find stop code.
                if (find_Stop2 != string::npos) {

                    line = line.substr(line.find("AUG"), find_Stop2);
                    code_Stop.push_back(line);                          // Adding it to code_Stop vector
                                                }

           find_Stop1 = line.find("UAA");                               //   finding all possible stop codes.
                if (find_Stop1 != string::npos) {
                    line = line.substr(line.find("AUG"), find_Stop1);     // Assign string code_1 from start code to UGA
                    code_Stop.push_back(line);                          //Adding to code_Stop vector
                                                }


           find_Stop3 = line.find("UAG");                               //  finding all possible stop codes.
                if (find_Stop3 != string::npos) {
                    line = line.substr(line.find("AUG"), find_Stop3);
                    code_Stop.push_back(line);                          //Adding to code_Stop vector
                                                }


            }



    }

    cout << '\n' << "Codes to use: " << endl;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < code_Assign.size(); i++)
            cout << code_Assign[i] << endl;

    cout << '\n' << "Possible Reading Frames: " << endl;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < code_Stop.size(); i++)
            cout << code_Stop[i] << endl;

    cout << endl;


    std::vector<std::string>::iterator longest = std::max_element(code_Stop.begin(), code_Stop.end, compare_length);

    std::string longest_line = *longest; // retrieve return value



    code_File.close();


}
else cout << "Cannot open File.";
```

to try and clarify my current output is this all in the code_Stop vector:

> Possible Reading Frames:
>
> AUG GGC CUC GAG ACC CGG GUU UAA AGU AGG
>
> AUG GGC CUC GAG ACC CGG GUU
>
> AUG AAA UUU GGG CCC AGA GCU CCG GGU AGC GCG UUA CAU

and I would just like to get the longest line.

Note, I am just learning about vectors, so please be kind...I have been getting a lot of help from this board and really much appreciated.

Ed. I changed the code to show where I have put it and it is giving me "Program received signal: 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'". What have I done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool compare_length(std::string const& lhs, std::string const& rhs) {
    return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> lines; // fill with data
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator longest = std::max_element(
                                           lines.begin(), lines.end(),
                                           compare_length);
    std::string longest_line = *longest; // retrieve return value
}
```

`compare_length` is a function that compares the length of two given strings. It returns `true` if the first string is shorter than the second one, and `false` otherwise.

`std::max_element` is a standard-algorithm that find the largest element in a sequence using the specified comparison-function. `lines.begin()` and `lines.end()` return iterators to the beginning and the end of the sequence `lines`, thus specifying the range the algorithm should scan.

Comment: @user1046825: I added an explanation. If you still don't understand, please tell what exactly you are having problems with.

Comment: This is probably a simple question, but what data is in lines? Is it the output that I already have?

Comment: And I am getting an error from max_element stating "Definition or redeclaration of 'max_element' not allowed inside a function.

Comment: @user1046825: `lines` contains the set of lines from which you want to find the longest. About your error, I cannot tell without seeing the code you wrote. This should probably be a separate question.

Comment: I don't know how to exactly use this code...I'm either worn out from doing hours of this stuff, or just don't understand the whole thing.

Comment: @user1046825: I had an error in my code, which I fixed now. My bad.

Comment: So am I pushing any data to lines?

Comment: @user1046825: No, you simply replace `lines` with whatever vector you actually want to use.

Comment: still not working, I added the code up top to show you where I put it in my program. Getting error.

Comment: I had another error in my code. Fixed it now. I also fixed your code, it should work now.

Comment: Thanks Again! Sorry for the inconvenience.